# Delete directories based on age of top level directory in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of folders in a directory, all contain many subdirectories of varying age.  What I need to do is delete the folders in there based on the age of the top level directories.  I've tried a few things, but what happens is it recurses the directories and deletes them.

For example, say I wanted to delete top-level folders older than 14 days (and their contents regardless of age):
C:\myfolder\folder1 (age 30 days)
C:\myfolder\folder1\subfolder1 (age 10 days)

I want to wipe out folder1 and all contents, even though subfolder1 is newer than 14 days....

Make sense?  I've tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\myfolder -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt 30 } | Remove-Item -Force
```

But that doesn't delete anything?  What am I missing here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing that you are excluding folders with `Where-Object{ !$_.PSIsContainer }`. So you are telling it not to include folders.

Plus you want a date to compare to a date.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\myfolder -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime  -lt (get-date).adddays(-29) } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: DOH!  Thank you so much.  I don't know that NOT operator got in there.  More coffee, please.  This works great now - thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The creationTime is a date, so you can't just compare it to a number:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\myfolder -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date.addDays(-30)) } | Remove-Item -Force
```